# Proof that geometric points are well defined

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Given a ring $A$ we defined a geometric point as the equivalence class (modulo the equivalence relation $\sim$) of a pair $(K,f)$ where $K$ is a field, $f:A\to K$ is a ring homomorphism, and $(K,f)\sim (K',f')$ if there is a $(L,g)$ such that $K,K'\subseteq L$ and $i\circ f=i\circ f'= g$, where $i$ is the inclusion. Now, I don't know how to prove that $\sim$ is a transitive relation: it seems to me that it is equivalent to showing that if two fields have a common subfield $K$, then they are both contained in some field extension of $K$. Is this intuition right? It seems simple but I can't find such an extension. Thanks for any hint

Comment: You should include a reference to where you have found this definition.

Comment: For your technical question: yes, if you have two field extensions of the same field, you can find a third field extension into which both embed. Take the tensor product – which will be non-zero! – then choose a maximal ideal and take the residue field.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't understand why choosing a maximal ideal (of the tensor product) and taking the residue field gives me an extension of the tensor product; it seems to me that this is not true in general

Comment: It doesn't. But that's not relevant – we only need to know we have an extension of the fields we started with.